# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Ajax update table - model

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to update a record list with ajax, represented on a table, where each record as an javascript delete link. If I preload the table, the RemoveLink works fine, but once the div "RecordListPartialView" is updated via ajax, It no longer works.

I checked with firebug that the generated html code is correct for each row. It looks like the browser isn't aware of the new code and so it doesn't trigger the javascript links.

Can someone please explain me what is going on?

(1) Here is the View code:

```js
$(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
    var _id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var recordToDelete = { id: _id };
    var json = $.toJSON(recordToDelete);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MortagePayment/RemoveMortageRecord',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#RecordListPartialView").empty();
            $("#RecordListPartialView").html(data.Message);
        }
    });
});
$(".AddLink").click(function () {
    var _year = $("#NewRecord_year").val();
    var _month = $("#NewRecord_month").val();
    var _mortageValue = $("#NewRecord_mortageValue").val();
    var newRecord = { year: _year, month: _month, mortageValue: _mortageValue };
    var json = $.toJSON(newRecord);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MortagePayment/AddMortageRecord',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#RecordListPartialView").empty();
            $("#RecordListPartialView").html(data.Message);

            $("#NewRecord_year").val(0);
            $("#NewRecord_month").val(0);
            $("#NewRecord_mortageValue").val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="RecordListPartialView">
    @Html.Partial("MortageRecordList", Model.MortageRecordList)
</div>
```

(2) the Partial View

```html
<table id="mortageRecordListTable">
    <tr>
        <th colspan=4>Current reductions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr id="row-@item.mortageRecordId">
            <td>
                @item.year
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.month
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.mortageValue
            </td>
            <td>                
                <p class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.mortageRecordId">Remove</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }              
</table>
```

(3) and the Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMortageRecord(MortageRecord newRecord) {
    var mortageRecordSet = MortageRecordSet.GetMortageSet(this.HttpContext);
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        mortageRecordSet.AddMortageRecord(newRecord);
    string partialViewHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("MortageRecordList", mortageRecordSet.GetMortageItems());

    return Json(new { Success = true, Message = partialViewHtml });
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RemoveMortageRecord(int id) {
    var mortageRecordSet = MortageRecordSet.GetMortageSet(this.HttpContext);
    mortageRecordSet.RemoveMortageRecord(id);              
    string partialViewHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("MortageRecordList", mortageRecordSet.GetMortageItems());

    return Json(new { Sucess = true, Message = partialViewHtml });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.

> If I preload the table, the RemoveLink works fine, but once the div
>   "RecordListPartialView" is updated via ajax, It no longer works.

Change your your `.click` event with `.live`

```
$(".RemoveLink").live("click",function(){
    //any click event code comes here
});
```

Comment: A small update here.  As of 1.7, you should use this instead:

$(".RemoveLink").on("click", function() { ... });

.live is depreciated as of 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you might need to call the click handler again in order to reattach it to the new DOM elements, since jQuery iterates through all the elements with the correct class when you actually call the `$(".RemoveLink").click()` and `$(".AddLink").click()` functions, not lazily whenever something is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

OK, do you have a jquery event in a separate .js script file and have attached an event to an element inside a PartialView?

well! if yes, whenever the PartialView renders itself again (no matter what is the reason) all of it's bound events will be gone! then you should rebind them again after rendering the PartialView.

there are different approaches, for example:

1. In the `Ajax.ActionLink` (or any ajax call that makes the
   PartialView re-render ) set OnSuccess to a jquery function that
   rebinds PartialView's events.
2. Move all of your jquery event bindings codes from separate .js
   script file to the inside of your PartialView's file (cstml). in
   this case every time PartialView has been rendered, those events
   will be bound again.